# Inconsistent printing results using same settings but different calibration models

Tags: pla, slic3r, renkforce-rf1000

I've got a second-hand Renkforce RF1000 [which I've gone into more detail about in this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13503/hardware-issues-id-appreciate-your-thoughts-on/).

The extruder works however, I get some inconsistent results. First I printed a calibration cube and noticed huge gaps in the bottom layer. Because of this, I increased the extrusion multiplier to 1.05. I noticed there still were some gaps but also other issues, I then printed one with the extrusion multiplier reset to 1.0 and a negative Z-offset. The results are shown below. In every image, the left cube has multiplier 1.0 and the right cube has multiplier 1.05.

[image: Calibration cube results]

Then, for a better idea about the consistency, I printed a hollow pyramid. This shows some heavy stringing. However, when printing a retraction test I barely get any stringing.

[image: Pyramid front]

[image: Pyramid bottom]

[image: Stringing test]

Does anyone know what could cause these inconsistent results? I assume some hardware tweaks might be needed, not just slicer settings. Any help is appreciated.

- I use Slic3r
- I use 3 mm PLA printed at 190 °C on a 60 °C bed with some glue (doesn't stick without). The first layer is 200 °C with a 65 °C bed.
- After three layers the fans are enabled.
- I have a negative Z-offset, it probably isn't calibrated 100 % correctly
- I don't know the nozzle size (a new one is being shipped) but use a size of 0.5 mm in the slicer
- retraction length 2 mm & 60 mm/s
- minimum travel after retraction 1 mm

Print settings:
[image: Settings]

EDIT:
After the recommendations I've changed the following:

- All belts have been recalibrated
- The e-steps have been recalibrated through [this](https://all3dp.com/2/extruder-calibration-6-easy-steps-2/) method. Couldn't do a wall measurement due to a lack of precise tools.
- Changed first layer temperature to 210 °C and other layers to 205 °C
- Added two top layers

I printed two new cubes. One without glue and with a Z-offset of 0.05 mm and one with glue and with a Z-offset of 0.15 mm. The results are quite comparable to the original ones although slightly better. Any recommendations?

I'm aware of some cooling issues on my prints. Once a new nozzle arrives I plan on printing the [current cooling system](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2239814) again. It's not really blowing air right effectively now.

[image: Cubes from below. Offset written on the bottom]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would try printing a little bit hotter, let's say arround 210 °C. Secondly, due to how the X and Y letters are being printed in the sides of the cube I would suggest to tigthen both the X and Y belts.

Regarding the gaps, I would first try a flow rate test. You could use a cube like [this one](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2490893).

Using:

- extrusion multiplier = 1
- layer height: 0.2 mm;
- layer width= 0.4 mm ;
- wall count= 2.

Then measure the walls with a caliper and you should have 0.8 mm walls. Do a couple of measurements, get the average and divide  0.8 by it  and multiply by a 100 (100*0.8/average). That's your new flow rate.

I would also try to add 1 or 2 top layers to the print.

For the first layer, I would definitely get a glass bed and use hairspray. The bottom of the pyramid doesn't seem to be sticking well. Apart from this, I'm not really fan of using Z-offset. Just try leveling a couple of times manually with a paper to get it right.

Comment: Also, for stringing try changing the retraction length to 5 mm and ~30 mm/s. See if in your slicer you can turn on the 'Combing' option

Comment: " to how the X and Y letters are being printed in the sides of the cube". How do you recognize this is printed incorrectly and the belts need tuning? Also I've got a heated ceramic bed, shouldn't that suffice? I don't see why a glass bed should be needed

Comment: Okay keep the ceramic bed, but try changing glue for hairspray, I really got better results... For the X and Y letters there's an artifact called ghosting/ripple. Here you can see what's about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaFp6Eqk0QI
Anyways, I think your main issue is flow rate... Try calibrating both this and E-Steps and send new pictures

Comment: Thank you but due to the bed being in an enclosure and being connected by wires I prefer to stick with glue as long as it works. I've uploaded some new prints with the other recommendations in place. Could you give your opinion?

Comment: I think it's much better, first layers and side walls are looking nice. Anyways, you will have to do a flow rate calibration (See the blobs in the X and Y letters)... Get a cheap caliper, it will worth it
 I think you're getting close to solving the problem. You'll just have to find the right slicing settings which is not that easy. Try printing a little bit slower

Comment: The problem got worse now that I've got a new nozzle and filament. It seems to be caused by the extruder. I've dedicated a new [question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13603/how-to-fix-bad-extrusion-thats-likely-caused-by-high-pressure-in-the-nozzle) to this problem. Thank you for the feedback, it did really help in improving the other problems and slicer settings.